# rails devise check class of logged in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have multiple models which are using devise like **Admin, Student and Counselor**

I don't want to use roles as it 'll complicate things in this case.

I want to use one layout and show menus etc. depending upon class of model like

```
= render "shared/#{resource.class}_menu"
```

Is there way that I can get class of logged in object without if else conditions like we do in **after_sign_in_path_for** etc.

Comment: I don't see other ways than having a helper method looping on possible connected type of users to see which one has a session. Also, in the case where a Counselor can also have a Student account, you'd need to check which entity's menu to show because both sessions can live simultaneously

Comment: wanted to avoid if else. though thanks

Answer (score 0):

So what I do in this case where you want to have different areas for  **Admin, Student and Counselor**

you can namespace each role or log in like this

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admins, :controllers => { registrations:  'admins/registrations',
                                       sessions:        'admins/sessions',
                                       passwords:       'admins/passwords',
                                       confirmations:   'admins/confirmations'
  }
  authenticate :admin do
    namespace :admins do
      ....
      root :to => 'something#index'
    end
  end

  devise_for : students, :controllers => { registrations:   'students/registrations',
                                           sessions:        'students/sessions',
                                           passwords:       'students/passwords',
                                           confirmations:   'students/confirmations'
  }
  authenticate :student do
    namespace :students do
      ....
      root :to => 'something#index'
    end
  end
```

Now you can create the devise model for each namespace.

```
#app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

end
```

For Devise controllers you can use them like tihs

```
#app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

end
```

For basic application controllers, you can use them like this.

```
#app/controllers/users/somethings_controller.rb
class Users::SomethingsController < UserController
...
end
```

I hope that this is able to help you